# Issue EntityFramework 5.0.0 connection with oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g, entity-framework-5

I am using EntityFramework 5.0.0 and my db is oracle11g client 12c Oracle Database (ODP.NET, Managed Driver) Version 12.1.My Database is already exists so i am calling existing tables and i connected my db using edmx its connected fine, But i am not using edmx in my actual application so i coded 1 entity and its configuration by hand, now its not connecting i think my connection string is wrong my web.config code is you can see connection string below

```
<configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
</configSections>

<connectionStrings>  
    <add name="dbContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=xxx;PASSWORD=aaa;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=aaaa&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />        
</connectionStrings>
```

Please tell me solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is my connection string which fixed connectivity issue.

```
<add name="dbContext" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=yourdatasource;PASSWORD=xxx;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=abc;" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
```

Make sure you are using EF 5.0.0 and ODAC 64-bit(if your machine is 64 bit) ODAC 12c Release 2 (12.1.0.1.2) Xcopy for Windows x64

Thanks